# Sending a string from c++ to JavaScript in cef3

Tags: javascript, c++, chromium-embedded

I am working on cef3 and I want to upload file with c++ and send this file data to JavaScript to manipulate with it. I add a JavaScript variable to receive data from c++ variable but I can't assign data to this JavaScript variable.

```
// Create a new V8 string value. See the "Basic JS Types" section below. 
CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> object = v8Context->GetGlobal(); 

// Add the string to the window object as "window.file". See the "JS Objects" section below. 
CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> str = CefV8Value::CreateString("this file variable"); 

object->SetValue("file", str, V8_PROPERTY_ATTRIBUTE_NONE);
```

this in function OnContextCreated to add javascript variable but i don't know to assign c++ string to this variable outside OnContextCreated function

Comment: Can you show and example of your code please.

Comment: You should put the code in your original Question. :)

Comment: @Jan Unless something has recently changed it's not automatic and you had to post the comment yourself. There is an _edit summary_ field on the edit page, this is where you put the information about the edit. When others view the change history that summary will be shown there.

Comment: what is not obvious in my question?

Comment: if any one know the answer please write it